# Trigger to prevent Insertion for duplicate data of two columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am working on `SQL Server 2008R2`, I am having the following Table

```
ID     Name     date
 1     XYZ      2010
 2     ABC      2011
 3     VBL      2010
```

Now i want to prevent insertion if i have a Data although the ID is different but data is present

```
 ID    Name     date
  4    ABC      2011
```

Kindly guide me how should i write this trigger.

Comment: Do you really need a trigger? Have you tried unique index or constraint?

Comment: and how to apply when my primary key is ID??

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX XXTable_Unq ON xxTable (name ASC,[date] ASC)

Comment: alow you can use this sql to insert: `insert into tb(name,date)select 'ABC',2048 from dual where not exists (select from tb where name='ABC')`

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
AFTER INSERT
AS

if exists ( select * from table t 
    inner join inserted i on i.name=t.name and i.date=t.date and i.id <> t.id)
begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('Duplicate Data', 16, 1);
end
go
```

That's just for insert, you might want to consider updates too.

**Update**

A simpler way would be to just create a unique constraint on the table, this will also enforce it for updates too and remove the need for a trigger. Just do:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]    
ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_ID_Name_Date] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [Name], [Date]
)
```

and then you'll be in business.

Comment: although this raise the error but cannot stop insertion, my problem is still there

Comment: Oh yep, that's because I missed the ROLLBACK line - so add that one in like I just have. But have a look at James's answer, maybe a unique constraint is what you're after.

Comment: If you need to use the trigger method (because you want a custom error message, for example) you will also need to check that you aren't accidentally joining inserted with the same record you just inserted.  I was always finding a duplicate until I added the equivalent of "i.id <> t.id" to the on clause.

Comment: The problem with unique constraint could be its max length (900B)

Comment: In my case a unique key would disrupt the balance in a massive congregation of running jobs and stored procs. I just want all that to continue as normal, but avoid the insert without an error being raised. Lots of use cases for this.

Comment: Scott's comment here contains a **key** piece of information and should be incorporated into this answer - you need to prevent rows in `inserted` matching *themselves* in the target table.

Comment: Thanks @Damien_The_Unbeliever and Scott Mitting for the fix, I've put it in.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using a store procedure inserting data into the table, you don't really need a trigger. You first check if the combination exists then don't insert.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_InsertData
@Name varchar(50),
@Date DateTime
AS
BEGIN

IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblData WHERE Name = @Name AND Date=@Date) = 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO tblData
                    ( Name, Date)
             VALUES (@Name, @Date)
        Print 'Data now added.'
     END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        Print 'Dah! already exists';
    END
END
```

The below trigger can used if you are not inserting data via the store procedure.

```
CREATE TRIGGER checkDuplicate ON tblData
AFTER INSERT
AS

IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblData A 
INNER JOIN inserted B ON B.name=A.name and A.Date=B.Date)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR ('Dah! already exists', 16, 1);
END
GO
```

Comment: the trigger can raise the error but the data is still inserting into the table, how to stop inserting the data

Answer (score 1):

One more choice, use an *insert instead* trigger.

```
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

if not exists (
    select *
    from MyTable t 
    inner join inserted i
       on i.name=t.name
       and i.date=t.date and i.id <> t.id )
begin
    Insert into MyTable (Name, Date) Select Name, Date from inserted
end
go
```

This is a good [discussion](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2013/01/24/sql-server-use-instead-trigger/) of how and when to use them.

Answer (score 1):

> This answer was inspired by the one on Apr 13 '20 at 18:34.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable  
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS  

if not exists (  
    select * from MyTable t   
    inner join inserted i
    on i.name=t.name and i.date=t.date and i.id <> t.id )  
begin  
    Insert into MyTable (Name, Date) Select Name, Date from inserted  
end  
else  
    THROW 51000, 'Statement terminated because a duplicate was found for the object', 1;      
go
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t really need a trigger for this. Just setup a unique constraint for multiple columns.

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TableName]    
ADD CONSTRAINT [UQ_ID_Name_Date] UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED
(
    [ID], [Name], [Date]
)
```

Comment: Shouldn't the constraint just be on the Name and Date columns?

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
 CREATE TRIGGER trg ON TableName
 AFTER INSERT 
 AS
  Begin
  Declare @id int,@name varchar(10),@date DateTime
  Declare @cnt1 int,@cnt2 int,@cnt3 int

  INSERT INTO TableName(ID, Name, Date) VALUES(4,'ABC',2011)
  select @id=ID,@name=Name,@date=Date from inserted

  select @cnt2=Count(*) from TableName where Name=@name
  select @cnt3=Count(*) from TableName where Date=@date

  if(@cnt2>1 or @cnt3>1)
    Rollback
  else 
    Commit

  end
```

Comment: This is full of bugs and won't work. Your insert statement has hard coded values, plus it will not allow data with duplicate names or dates or even IDs.

Comment: The requirement is not to allow duplicates even different id, right?