# Why does my trigger to avoid duplicate rows not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Before anyone suggests a unique index or key, I have a very good case for this.

I am using this trigger, from [Trigger to prevent Insertion for duplicate data of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18502802/8741):

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogDuplicates ON bkPersonPoints
FOR INSERT
AS
if exists (select * from bkPersonPoints c 
                    inner join inserted i 
                        on c.Name = i.Name and c.Points = i.Points)
begin
    rollback
end
GO
```

That answer is accepted and has 15 up-votes, so I would expect it to work, yet even on my very first insert, into an empty table:

```
insert bkPersonPoints (Name, Points) values ('Brady', 100)
```

I get the error:

> The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

**APPENDIX**: The table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[bkPersonPoints](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Points] [int] NOT NULL
) ON [APP_BR2_User]
```

Comment: Scott's comment on that answer contains a key piece of information - you need to ensure that the rows in `inserted` **don't** match *themselves* in the table (since this is a `for`/`after` trigger, the inserted rows are already in the table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening because it is detecting the record you're currently inserting to the table.  You need to filter that out of the `EXISTS` clause:

```
CREATE TRIGGER LogDuplicates ON bkPersonPoints
FOR INSERT
AS
if exists (select * from bkPersonPoints c 
                    inner join inserted i 
                        on c.Name = i.Name 
                        and c.Points = i.Points
                        and c.id <> i.id)
begin
    rollback
end
GO
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I did have some doubt about the record already existing AFTER INSERT but in my clamoring for an answer the PK idea eluded me.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, suggest CONSTRAINT

```
ALTER TABLE bkPersonPoints
  ADD CONSTRAINT c_uniq_Name_and_points UNIQUE (Name, Points)
```

Comment: **Literally** the first line of the question starts "Before anyone suggests a unique index or key..."

Comment: Better be a darn good case to not use the specific database feature designed to handle this exact situation...

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, but i guess, that there is no point to use trigger for check uniqueness, so i've suggested :3

Comment: My use case is top not necessarily merely prevent the record being inserted, but to log the potential duplicate and hopefully something about what caused the duplicate insert. I may even need to not prevent the insert, but just zero out the amount on a duplicate. A unique key is useless for any of that except preventing the insert.

Answer (score 0):

> This answer was inspired by one posted on Apr 13 '20 at 18:34 in [Trigger to prevent Insertion for duplicate data of two columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502802/trigger-to-prevent-insertion-for-duplicate-data-of-two-columns/67775573#67775573).

CREATE TRIGGER MyTrigger ON dbo.MyTable
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS

if not exists (
select * from MyTable t
inner join inserted i
on i.name=t.name and i.date=t.date and i.id <> t.id )
begin
Insert into MyTable (Name, Date) Select Name, Date from inserted
end
else
THROW 51000, 'Statement terminated because a duplicate was found for the object', 1;
go